# How toView attached files from a og

Tags: organic-groups, views

my first question here. 
Drupal 7
OG 7.2

I'm trying to make a view to display a list of attached files to a group. 
I've made a custom field for the attachments in the content type for posts and in there comments.

I've achieve to display the view, both for private files and public. 
Ok ! I was very happy after hours of pain.

The problem is that the view is pulling all the files from all groups.
What I want it's to see the group files. 
How do I get the relation between the file and the group ?
 Any help would be appreciated.

Bellow it's a image of the view, I hope you can understand it. (field_anexos_de_grupo) it's the media field.
Note: I'm new to drupal and I'm not a php expert.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to also to add the relation between the file to the current viewed groups with the OG membership relationship. You can have a look how this done in a view called "OG content"

Comment: Thanks ! I've try to replicate the OG content, changing the fields to get the attach files. But for me it's like the lottery ...Perhaps you could point me in the write direction. When creating a view, it's best to be a content , or file ?